# How does one get "savetxt.numpy" to run using 'b' as my format designator?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 1 by 30000 element array of type uint32.
Call it my_array.

When I try the following:

```
np.savetxt('test.txt', my_array, fmt='%.32b')
```

I get the following error:
ValueError: unsupported format character 'b' (0x62) at index 4

Any suggestions to get my line of code to run.

I want a visual output of my_array in binary form expanded to 32 numbers if needed.
Note 'b' is not popular and I had to locate it using footnote links in Numpy.
I am using Python 3.8

Comment: `savetxt` uses `fmt%tuple(row)` where `fmt` is constructed from your `fmt` parameter (replicated for the number of columns).  That is, it uses the standard Python `%` formatting.  If you don't like anything that offers, format your own array, and write it directly to a file.  It won't be any slower.

Comment: I am looking but I cannot find a way to format the values in my array.

Comment: I don't know what you intend by a 'b/binary' format.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting

Comment: In case it isn't clear, the letter codes in python string formatting are unrelated to the codes numpy uses for `dtype`.

Comment: Is this what you want https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.binary_repr.html?highlight=bin#numpy.binary_repr - `np.binary_repr`; 
Or https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html - python `bin`

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The new style formatter does have a `b` converter, which could be used as:

```
In [205]: x = np.arange(0,1000,123)
In [206]: x
Out[206]: array([  0, 123, 246, 369, 492, 615, 738, 861, 984])
In [207]: fmt=', '.join(['{:010b}']*len(x))
In [208]: fmt
Out[208]: '{:010b}, {:010b}, {:010b}, {:010b}, {:010b}, {:010b}, {:010b}, {:010b}, {:010b}'
In [209]: fmt.format(*x)
Out[209]: '0000000000, 0001111011, 0011110110, 0101110001, 0111101100, 1001100111, 1011100010, 1101011101, 1111011000'
```

`savetxt` iterates on the rows of a 2d array, and does a

```
f.write(fmt%tuple(row))
```

where `fmt` is constructed as I did, but with the `%` fmt parameter you provide.  This new style format could be used in the same way. `savetxt` is plain Python text file writing.